# Serializing an XML Payload with JAXB in a jax-rs Rest End Point

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-rs

Ok, So i've genetrated my java classes from my xsd file using jaxb. I've also written the following code as an endpoint which recieves a request (XML). Now I'd like to read the request into my java objects I can then use these to insert into my DB. Is this the correct way i should be implementing this? If so, how is it done? Thanks

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/xml")
@Produces("application/xml")
public String registerPost(@Context HttpServletRequest req) {

    try {
        //update DB
    } catch (DatabaseException e) {
        return "Fail";
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _read the request into my java objects_? What DB? What do you think is the correct way to do it? Are you expecting us to write it for you?

Comment: You should put the JAXB class that represents the payload as a parameter (rather than the HttpServletRequest).

Comment: Thanks John. I think that answers my question. I saw that solution but wasn't sure about it. I'll give it a go.

Comment: @Bazzoner you're welcome. I've also added an answer with this solution. Feel free to accept it, if you think it is the right one.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I know a few people are downvoting this question, but it seems pretty clear to me. My summation - he wants to know how to convert the request into his JAXB Objects, which he can then use productively. The provided signature of the REST endpoint indicates that this is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this helps a little :

- Your jax-rs end point can accept your JAXB class directly (providing your server has been configured with a JAXB provider).  It will handle the conversion from incoming text to appropiate Java objects for you.
- You don't specifically need the Servlet Request Object.
- You may need to convert your JAXB entities into JPA entities before you can save them to the database (or add both JAXB and JPA annotations to the same classes).
- Your return type should be text/plain rather than XML (or you should return XML).

  ```
  @POST
  @Consumes("application/xml")
  @Produces("text/plain")
  public String registerPost(MyEntityClass payload) {

   try {
       //update DB
       myService.save(payload);
       return "success";
   } catch (DatabaseException e) {
       return "Fail";
   }

  }
  ```